# Unsynonym ntp from time

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I have a subscription for [ntp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ntp). It seems that recently [ntp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ntp) became a synonym for [time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/time), so that I now get questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234446/bios-time-is-incorrect) (which is not related to ntp) via my subscription.

Please remove this synonym: [ntp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ntp) should be for questions specific to [ntp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) (i.e. using `ntpd`, `nptdate` et.al.), not for all questions regarding the 4th dimension.

**EDIT:** This seems to be solved. Could a mod please check what happened with [ntp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ntp)? Its [history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/51064/revisions) offers no clues.

Comment: While yes, I feel as if the two dont blend perfectly, a request for desynonimization would include more reasons why the tag is currently unwanted.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: I'm reasonably sure that the synonym is new. Anyway, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The history as far as I understand it.

`ntp` was requested to be a synonym by a senior member of the Ask Ubuntu community (no names required to be mentioned).

Yesterday, another similar synonym creation question was requested and was granted.

At the same time a number of outstanding synonyms that were requested by other senior members for quite a considerable amount of time were actioned which included ntp --> time.

This particular request was revoked today by an AU mod - probably after reading this Q&A and acting on the relatively high number upvotes given to a AU meta question.

The history link you have given is for edits to the tag - not for synonym creation.  Looks like no actual history is recorded for these.

---

There are a number of outstanding synonym requests - for those in the community with high enough rep - please review these and either upvote or downvote the requests.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a status-completed tag (or something to that effect), please?